# How do I create a global date that can be accessed and changed by any view controller in swift?

Tags: swift, class, date, model, static

Here is the code I came up with:

```
import Foundation

class MonthToAdjust {
    
    static var date = Date()
    
    init(date: Date) {
        MonthToAdjust.self.date = date
    }
    
    static func increaseDateByAMonth() {
        MonthToAdjust.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: MonthToAdjust.date)!
    }
    static func decreaseDateByAMonth() {
        MonthToAdjust.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: MonthToAdjust.date)!
    }
    
}
```

It has a static variable for the date.

There are 2 static functions that either increase or decrease the date by a month.

Is this correct? Is there a better way?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a singleton - you can see [What is a singleton?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-singleton)

Comment: What is the goal here and how/when will the init be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you have is okay. Minor point: you don't need to create a new Date() in the init() method if you're creating it at initialization of the var.

The other approach would be to use a shared singleton object - here it's the object itself that is static, while the members are regular instance variables, e.g.

```
import Foundation

class MonthToAdjust {
    
    static var shared = MonthToAdjust()

    var date
    
    init(_ date: Date = Date()) {
        self.date = date
    }
    
    func increaseDateByAMonth() {
        self.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: 1, to: self.date)!
    }
    func decreaseDateByAMonth() {
        self.date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: -1, to: self.date)!
    }
}
```

You can then do this in your code:

```
MonthToAdjust.shared.date = Date() // reset to now, or set to another date similarly
MonthToAdjust.shared.increaseByAMonth()
MonthToAdjust.shared.decreaseByAMonth()
let dateCopy = MonthToAdjust.shared.date // do something with current value
```

Answer (score 2):

As already suggested in comment you can create a singleton class. Just make sure you declare the initializer as private to avoid creating multiple instances of the singleton class:

```
class Singleton {
    static var shared = Singleton()
    var date = Date()
    private init() { }
}
```

---

If you would like to add a month to a particular date you can extend Date and create a mutating method to add component values to your date:

```
extension Date {
    mutating func add(_ component: Calendar.Component, value: Int) {
        self = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: component, value: value, to: self)!
    }
}
```

---

Note that the date property value will be initialized the first time you access the shared property:

---

```
print(Singleton.shared.date)  // "2020-09-16 20:22:04 +0000\n"
Singleton.shared.date.add(.month, value: 1)
print(Singleton.shared.date)  // "2020-10-16 20:22:04 +0000\n"
```